# Reverse data back to input sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have made a data from, to put data inside an inputsheet to a datasheet. Now I want to be able to get the data back from the input  to the datasheet, to be able to make changes to the already existing data. Is this possible?

This is the script im using.

````
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('NIEUW Invoerbestand');
  const inputSheet =ss.getSheetByName('Input')
  const idCell = ss.getRangeByName('Barcode');
  const id = idCell.getValue();
  const cellFound = dataSheet.getRange('A:A')
    .createTextFinder(id)
    .matchCase(true)
    .matchEntireCell(true)
    .findNext()
  if (!cellFound) return;
  const fieldRange = inputSheet.getRange('Input!E4:E241');
  const fieldValues = [fieldRange.getValues().flat()];
  dataSheet
    .getRange(cellFound.getRow(), 6)
    .offset(0, 0, fieldValues.length, fieldValues[0].length)
    .setValues(fieldValues);
  fieldRange.clearContent();
  idCell.clearContent();```
````

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `Now I want to be able to get the data back from the input to the datasheet, to be able to make changes to the already existing data. Is this possible?` and your showing script. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: HI, I want to be able to get the data, that i've put from the input sheet to the data sheet (with the script i'm showing). back to the input sheet. so For example i have data in my Datasheet under the name 'test001' in IDcell. I want to be able to find this data back whenever I search for Test001 in IDcell 
So basically a 'search' function. If IDCell is a code that has already data written in the datasheet, it will copy that data back to to the inputsheet

Comment: The script that I showed is the script im using to put data from the inputsheet to the data sheet, now im trying to make a script that does the opposite

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `now im trying to make a script that does the opposite`, replacing the source and destination sheet is your expected result? If I misunderstood your reply, I apologize.

Comment: Yes thats what I would like to have!

Comment: Hi, The issue has not been resolved yet, cause I have no idea how to write a script that does the opposite, whenever I find a working script I will post it!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I noticed that I might have misunderstood `now im trying to make a script that does the opposite`. So, I posted a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `now im trying to make a script that does the opposite`, in order to achieve your goal, how about modifying your script as follows?

#### From:

```
const fieldRange = inputSheet.getRange('Input!E4:E241');
const fieldValues = [fieldRange.getValues().flat()];
dataSheet
  .getRange(cellFound.getRow(), 6)
  .offset(0, 0, fieldValues.length, fieldValues[0].length)
  .setValues(fieldValues);
fieldRange.clearContent();
```

#### To:

```
const range = dataSheet.getRange(cellFound.getRow(), 6, 1, dataSheet.getLastColumn() - 5);
range.copyTo(inputSheet.getRange("E4"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, true);
range.clearContent();
```

- When this modified script is run, the row values of the searched row of "NIEUW Invoerbestand" sheet are moved to `Input!E4` as a column. I thought that this situation might be `now im trying to make a script that does the opposite`.

Comment: @CeePee98 Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your question by your cooperation. Thank you, too.